# Problema com Hibernate e servidor WildFly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

Olá.

Tenho um projeto com Hibernate 4.3.x + PostgreSql + WildFly. Mas não consigo executá-lo.

Segue o erro:

```
Iniciando WildFly Application Server
WildFly Application Server iniciado
Implantação inicial de WebApplication1 até C:\wildfly-11.0.0.Beta1\standalone\deployments\WebApplication1.war
Distribuição inicial do WebApplication1 completada
Implantando C:\wildfly-11.0.0.Beta1\standalone\deployments\WebApplication1.war
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.persistenceunit.\\\"WebApplication1.war#ConfeccaoPU\\\"\" => \"java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory\"}}"
C:\Projects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1074: O módulo não foi implantado.
```

Alguem sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: `org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory` - Isso dá a entender que você tem algum problema com `ClassLoader`s. Esse problema tende a ser algo complexo e nada óbvio, mas sem ver o seu código não tem como saber onde está o erro.

Comment: Acho que [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533847/wildfly-10-java-lang-classcastexception-org-dom4j-documentfactory-cannot-be-ca) no SO pode lhe ajudar

Comment: Esse erro apareceu quando tentei abrir o projeto em outro computador. Uso o NetBeans e vi no Google para adicionar as dependências no arquivo pom.xml do maven mas não utilizo o maven